# Wordpress plugin for activating other plugins

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Hi iam developing a plugin to activated a couple of plugins. i.e: the plugin jetpack has six plugins and all gets activated on a single install,like wise i need to activate a group of plugins from acivating this plugin.

for example consider a plugin called 'site plugin' which has sub folders of other plugins.
when i activate 'site plugin' it should show options to activate other plugins in it.

I hope some one could help me.

Comment: Are these child plugins developed by third parties or are they all your own code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're main pluggin can use [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) and use the function you register thru the hook to activate you're necesary pluggins.

Smth along these lines :

```
    // get already activated plugins
    $plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
    $puginsToActiv = array('Plugin1', 'Plugin2', 'Plugin3');
    if($plugins)
    {
        $changed = false;
        foreach ($puginsTostActiv as $plugin)
        {
            if (!in_array($plugin, $plugins))
            {
                $changed = true;
                array_push($plugins,$plugin);
            }
        }

        if ( $changed )
            update_option('active_plugins',$plugins);
    }
// code not tested
```

Comment: Or you could use activate_plugin() found in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php

Comment: @scribu : yes you could use that too